# How to measure the time spent managing memory

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, metrics

This [reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1931qv/imperfect_allocation_of_memory/) has drawn my attention on custom memory allocators. User Rohmboid says, for instance:

> People wouldn't be writing their own pool allocators it if there
>   wasn't a clear benefit.

How do they know there is one?

I don’t want to waste my time/money/energy on writing a custom allocator if the time spent managing memory only accounts for less than 1% of the duration of my program. Neither do I want to switch to a custom allocator and be unable to tell the speedup.  So I am wondering: how can I measure (or at least, estimate) the time spent allocating/freeing/fetching memory?

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler?

Comment: Speaking personally for the latest project I've worked on we went down the road of assuming we needed one for a system which was going to have a ton of allocations. After testing we decided it was pretty hard to beat regular old `new` for small allocations. It seems that (in VS2010 on windows 7 at least) repeated small allocations are ungodly fast.

Comment: People don't write custom allocators to make them *faster*, but to manage memory more effectively.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Which usually makes the program faster.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz A simple specialized allocator is rarely slower than general-purpose `malloc`/`new`, true, but in some circles the primary motivation is reduced space overhead and reduced fragmentation. In fact, that's what pool allocators are even better at than at performance (no per-block space overhead; space can be used 100% regardless of allocation history).

Comment: People have been known to do lots of things that make absolutely no sense whatsoever... unless _measurements_ show that this is performance critical, leave it alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I know there is one?

## Profile your code.

There's no point optimizing something that isn't a hot path in your code.

If the Allocator (A) takes 5% of your CPU time, and your app takes the other 95%, speeding the allocator up twice gives you `(5/2)/100 = 2.5%` boost. Now try to speed up B by even a fraction.

#### How?

The easiest way is to use the IDE built-in profiler; MSVS one is rather decent, although I am using Intel VTune; its ease of use is really great, and it just shows you - optimize *here*.

Using the profiling program has the additional benefit; you don't have to modify your code at all; you also don't have to recompile when you want to change profiling options and run again. That being said, timers in your application can also give nice results, although they rarely need to be placed *directly* inside allocator. It's better to continuously narrow the possible places where the program takes the most time.

Comment: @qdii I'd like to add another possible benefit of writing a own allocator. In case the programmer has deeper insight for allocation behavior, he can take assumptions general purpose allocates are not allowed to make. This gives the possibility to optimize the allocation for various parameters, not only speed. For example knowing the fact that there is a fixed size that gets allocated for a certain application could help to avoid the risk of **heap fragmentation** by creating a specific allocator. And that's only one example.

Comment: @junix Custom memory allocation is a complicated topic, beyond the scope of this answer, I think. Your comment is most welcome, though.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. I just thought the discussion is a bit too "speed based" and wanted to illustrate that other parameters could matter for this decision. That's why I decided to just vote up your answer and post a comment instead of creating an "alternative" one.